# How to modify this code to print the 3 integers in order?

Tags: java

I have a code that prints the biggest integer between 3 integers and I want to sort these 3 integers (like `num < num1 < num2`).

I want to modify my code to achieve this, how can I do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class digits {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int big = 0;
    System.out.println("Please insert 3 numbers: ");
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (number.hasNextInt()) {
      num = number.nextInt();
      big = num;
    }
    if (number.hasNextInt()) {
      num1 = number.nextInt();
      if (num1 > num) {
        big = num1;
      }
    }
    if (number.hasNextInt()) {
      num2 = number.nextInt();
      if (num2 > num && num2 > num1) {
        big = num2;
      }
      System.out.println(big + ">" + num1 + ">" + num);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Error: Invalid Value.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Go back and look at your notes, read through your textbook, and start working on it. Later, if you have a specific question about something, come back and ask and people will be a lot more willing to help you. We're not gonna do your homework for you.

Comment: Can you write your specifications. If you can use builtin sort algorithms, you can use them. Or you can write your sorting algorithm. But we need to know what are the constraints to solve this problem.

Comment: I edited the post, if I enter for example 30 as num, 25 as num1 and 20 as num2, it print 30>25>30 so there's a problem and I don't find answers

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please insert 3 numbers: ");
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);

    Integer[] input = new Integer[3];
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 3) {
        input[i++] = number.nextInt();
    }
    number.close();
    Arrays.sort(input, Collections.reverseOrder());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Integer a : input) {
        sb.append(a).append(">");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code: you're choosing the biggest of the three numbers (big), but you never change num1 or num.
So, your result will always be: greater `number>second value` from `System.in>third value` from `System.in`.

In other words, you're sorting only the higher value.

Comment: how can I find the second highest number?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(num1>num)
{
    big=num1;
}
```

Change this to:

```
if(num1>num)
{
    big=num1;
}
else
{
    // swap num1 and num
    int tmp = num;
    num = num1;
    num1 = num;
}
```

Also change

```
if(num2>num && num2>num1)
{
    big=num2;
}
```

to

```
if(num2>num1)
{
    big=num2;
}
else
{
    // num1 is largest, so swap num1 and num2
    int tmp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = tmp;
    if(num > num1){
        //swap num and num1
        int t = num1;
        num1 = num;
        num = t;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class digits {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] nums = new int[3];
    int k = 0;
    System.out.println("Please insert 3 numbers: ");
    Scanner number = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (number.hasNext() && k < 3) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(number.nextLine());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Value.");
        }
        nums[k] = i;
        k++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    System.out.println(nums[2]+ ">" +nums[1]+ ">" +nums[0]);

  }
}
```